# 404 Error Express Routes

Tags: javascript, express, routes, ejs

I'm having problems when I try to access other routes from the index page.  I can hit the index no problem but any other route I get a 404 error.  The other routes are pretty much I the same so I'm not sure what's going on.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Here is my app.js:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var aboutRouter = require('./routes/about');
var workRouter = require('./routes/work');
var projectRouter = require('./routes/projects');
var donateRouter = require('/routes/donate');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/about', aboutRouter);
app.use('/work', workRouter);
app.use('/projects', projectRouter);
app.use('/donate', donateRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Here is the index.js route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index'){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the new about.js route:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET about page. */
router.get('/about', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('about page'){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm using partials, so here's the header.ejs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Africa Foundation</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/main.css' />
    <script src='/javascripts/fontawesome-all.min.js'></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img id='af-logo-nav' src='/images/swirl.png'>
        <span>Africa Foundation</span>
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/work">Our Work</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/projects">Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link btn-btn-warning" href="/donate">Donate</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="bg">
```

Comment: How are you hitting these endpoints front the front end? Could you show your front end code? Or if you're using a REST client like postman or something

Comment: I updated with a bit of the front end.

Answer (score 1):

I believe with your current code the route you would need to hit would be /about/about for it to work.  Check if that works and if it does. Change your app.use('about', aboutRouter) to app.use(aboutRouter). Then your route should work as expected. This is because setting 'about' in app.use sets a sortof virtual route

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

> res.send("about page")

can you please change it to something simple names like

> "about"

like that sometimes spaces make trouble. I think that might work.